# Loopback is not defined

Tags: loopback

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
D:\PPL\Laundry\Front\api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

ReferenceError: loopback is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add this line to fix this Error

    var loopback = require('loopback');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  ];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

This could be a sample `server.js`. Please make sure that `loopback` module is referred.